# Laravel vendor files

Tags: laravel

I am working on an application with laravel 8, whenever I run `composer update` 5000+ vendor files are tracked by GitHub however `/vendor` is added into the `.gitignore` file. here is a snap of my .gitignore file:

[image: .gitignore image]

Answer (score 2):

Might be possible that you have already staged/added the vendor folder before putting in the `.gitignore` file. Or you have manually staged/added the folder to git through command.

In any case, one solution for you is to unstage the files by using

```
git reset /vendor/*
```

and if this doesn't solve your problem, then it might be possible that you already have committed older files into git; so, `/vendor` files are getting tracked by git.

Solution steps:

1. Delete the `/vendor` folder.
2. Make a clean commit of tracked files inside `/vendor` (if there are any)
3. Run `composer install` again to get back `/vendor` folder.

After these steps, vendor will not be tracked. (Considering `/vendor/` is still present in the `.gitignore` file)

Comment: i found the issue after your answer, yes the vendor directory is committed before to the repo, so it is exiting in the repo.

Comment: just delete and commit again. after that, the issue will not show up